# CORS Error - Even with correct headers set

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have a FE made with react and a BE with node/express/mongodb/mongoose. This is my first attempt at trying to connect everything together. As far as I am aware everything is correct but I am still getting a CORS error but I have no idea why.

this is from my app.js in my back end

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use((res, req, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');

    next();
});
```

Instead of the wildcard I tried specifically to add 'http://localhost:3000' but that still does not work as I get the CORS error. I am pretty new to the back end so I could easily be doing something wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: For anyone who finds this from google. The below answers did work great (installing cors package) but I also figured the issue out which works without the package. The main issue was if you see my middleware function states `(res, req, next)`, I accidentally but the response first before the request which was causing these issues. So it should be `(req, res, next)` I did not know this would even cause an issue so it was interesting to figure out. Hope this helps anyone in the future. One thing that did help was the cors package actually gave me some information on why it wasn't working which helped me figure it out. The error that I was receiving was because res.setHeader wasn't a function, and for some reason this is true if the response is before the request in the middleware function

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 things you can do:

- Set proxy in react package.json. For example: { "proxy": "http://localhost:3000" }
- Or you can use cors in the backend: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Thank you, I will try the cors package. But for curiosity sake is there a particular reason why this is necessary? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: it's for security reason. If it's not on the same "server" and it's not if it's on the different ports. (BTW, wish I know, why I was down-vote... )

Comment: Yes I understand the security reason and it is because they are on different ports. More so my question was specifically about why I would need the CORS package even though I set them correctly in my code haha. Also not sure why you are down voted either, everything on this page was downvoted for some reason

Comment: If your front end using react, and the proxy is set in package.json correctly, you don't need cors in backend. (As far as I know.)

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the information. This is my first time creating a BE from scratch so I enjoy learning. I did figure out the issue though, you can see my edit in the original post if you are curious!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding cors to your app.

```
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors"); //Add this

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use((res, req, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');

    next();
});
app.use(cors()); //And add this line as well
```

Comment: Thank you, the other answer also suggested this. I will try it and see if it works!